# Generating an error message for unknown keys

Tags: l3keys

The code below outputs:

> ERROR: Package Foo Error: Unknown key, \l_keys_key_tl

Why does `\l_keys_key_tl` expand at Hook 1, not Hook 2?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

  \msg_new:nnn
  {Foo}
  {generic}
  {#1}

  \keys_define:nn { \__erw_foo_options }
  {
    key .value_required:n = true,

    unknown .code:n =
    {
      { Unknown~key,~\l_keys_key_tl}  % Hook 1

      \msg_error:nnn
      { Foo }
      { generic }
      { Unknown~key,~\l_keys_key_tl} % Hook 2
    }
  }

  \NewDocumentCommand{\FooOptions}
  {m}
  {
   \keys_set:nn { \__erw_foo_options } {#1}
  }

 \NewDocumentCommand{\FooTest}
 {}
 {

   \FooOptions{bar}

 }


  \ExplSyntaxOff

  \begin{document}

\FooTest

  \end{document}
```

Comment: IIRC, the error message for unknown keys comes for free with `l3keys`. There should be no need to explicitly handle this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expansion behaviour of `\msg_error:nnn`, etc., is tightly defined: they pass the third (fourth, etc.) arguments unchanged. As such, you want to expand the variable using `\msg_error:nnx`. In contrast, just 'dumping the text' will convert the `tl` to its expansion at point-of-typesetting: this is the documented behaviour of token lists.

Comment: Also, `\keys_define:nn { \__erw_foo_options }` uses `\__erw_foo_options` _literally_ as the family for keys: you almost certainly mean something like `\keys_define:nn { erw } ...`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Is the non-expanding behavior of `\msg_new:nnn` something that has changed in the last 3 years or so? Because I have code where I used `\exp_not:n` in the third argument of `\msg_new:nnn`, as if it were handled by `\message`... but this would appear to be unnecessary. Remark: `\l_keys_key_tl` appears to work, but my `interface3.pdf` doesn't document it (it documents `\l_keys_key_str`, which also works).

Comment: @JosephWright I guess you meant `\keys_define:nn { __erw_foo_options }` (a name, not a token)?

Comment: @JosephWright Ah, I see in the `.dtx`: “`\begin{variable}{\l_keys_key_str, \l_keys_key_tl}` The |tl| version is deprecated but has to be handled manually.”. @Erwann I'm not Joseph, but I'd say “no”. The first argument of `\keys_define:nn` is usually the package name (and `erw` is three tokens).

Comment: @frougon. OK, I get it.